# Using CSS in input attribute from html to asp:Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I'm using JQuery from "https://github.com/yairEO/validator " to have client side validation in my project.

The code is using html input textbox but now I'm using asp:Textbox.

I do not know what's causing the problem for the validation to not work in asp:textbox but it's working for `<input >` textbox. Is it because of the CSS names?

Here is the code.
    CSS

```
.item .alert {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 3px 4px 4px 3px;
  background-color: #CE5454;
  max-width: 170px;
  white-space: pre;
  position: relative;
  left: -15px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.15s ease-out;
  font-size: 12px
}
.item .alert::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-color: transparent #CE5454 transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 11px 7px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -13px;
  top: 1px;
}
.item.bad .alert {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
.item label,
.item .label {
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.item label span,
.item .label {
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  line-height: 2em;
}
.item input,
.item textarea {
  float: left;
  padding: 3px 4px;
  width: 210px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.item input[type=checkbox] {
  width: auto;
}
.label ~ label {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0.3em 1.2em 0 0;
}
.item input.short {
  width: 90px;
}
.item input:focus:not([type="checkbox"]),
.item textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #00AEEF;
  border: 1px solid #00AEEF;
}
.item textarea {} .item select {
  float: left;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 2px 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.item select option {
  padding: 1px;
}
.item > .extra {
  float: left;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: #999;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin-left: 13px;
}
.item.multi .input {
  float: left;
}
.item.multi input {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}
form .item.multi input:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  margin: 0;
}
.item.items input {
  border-top: 5px solid #E1E1E1;
  margin: 0 0 0 160px;
}
.bad input,
.bad select,
.bad textarea {
  border: 1px solid #CE5454;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px -2px #CE5454;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  -moz-animation: .7s 1 shake linear;
  -webkit-animation: 0.7s 1 shake linear;
}
```

And this is the HTML with asp.net textbox, it's working for the  but once i remove that it wont work for asp:textbox anymore.

```
<div class="item"><label>
<asp:TextBox ID="cust_name" title="Customer Name" runat="server" onblur="myFunction()"  CssClass="buttonstyle" placeholder="Customer Name" ></asp:TextBox><br><br>
<input  id= "textbox" name="t_date" placeholder="ex. 2015 / 07 / 06" required="required" /></label></div>
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your function 'myFunction()' is correct and called, Try to do that in firebug.

Comment: I assume a <asp:Textbox> renders into a textarea?

Comment: everything works when i use <input.. /> textbox, but when i use asp:textbox it doesn't.

Comment: @Samuel - Please put rendered html of asp:TextBox, this will help :)

Comment: How do I do that @r.piesnikowski ? Sorry, I'm still new to this. Step by step would be very helpful!